# How to display title on html dropdown items for non-javascript browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am using ASP.Net MVC 2.0 with C#.
I have a html dropdown control on my page which may contain items with longer text. The page design does not allow me to increase the drop down width so that I can display entire text for each item. To overcome this, I am trying to display a title on mouse over of each item so that use can see the item text. This is achievable using javasctipt and I am happy with the solution. But what if the client has disabled javascript on his browser? Is there any way we can display title for each drop down item without depending on javascript? May be using the "title" attrbute of option or something simillar? I am targeting my code to work for IE8 clients.

Following is my current implementation. I have called a javascript function on mousemove. This loops through drop down options and assigns the selected value to the title attribute of selected option.

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedTeamId, new SelectList((IEnumerable)""), "Please Select", new { @class = "wid140", id = "QueryTeam", onmousemove ="ShowSelectedText(this);"})%>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the "title" attribute like you suggested?

Comment: Title will work. But the question is how to assign the title for each element filled in Html.DropDownListFor?

Comment: `title` does not work for me on Chrome and IE9. Seems to me there is no way.